# Hide history buttons in inAppBrowser Plugin Cordova 3 +

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm using android, cordova 3.4.1+ and latest inAppBrowser plugin. I  need the toolbar with `Done` button and without `history buttons` and `url location`

So with this follwing line I've successfully removed the url position. But the history buttons are still showing.

```
window.open('http://example.com/some.jpg','_blank','location=no,toolbar=yes,EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

Oh! And I also needed some tweaking in the `.java` file to make the toolbar visible while `location=no`

But I can't find anyway to hide the history buttons. Can anyone please tell me how to hide the history buttons? Is it possible to do that by tweaking plugin's `.java` file? If not possible, is it possible to control the behaviour of the buttons from javascript? For example I want to set 'where to go next' for those history buttons........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any way to control those history buttons behaviour yet.Like pressing forward will take to a new pre-defined address. I don't think that exists now. To `hide` those buttons , Go to

```
platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\inAppBrowser.java
```

Find these lines

```
// Add the back and forward buttons to our action button container layout
actionButtonContainer.addView(back);
actionButtonContainer.addView(forward);
```

Comment them out.

Answer (score 1):

you can handle through overriding buttons with listener.. check loadstart eventlistener and get event.url which gives your current location url, compare that and give appropriate action which u want to provide through which u can handle history. if you want to stop loading page on back then give actions once comparing url is true.

```
var ref = window.open('http://example.com/some.jpg', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

// handling event listener

```
ref.addEventListener("exit", function () {
    //logic here
});

     ref.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
     ref.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);



function iabLoadStart(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
       if(event.url=="http://example.com")
       {
           //your logic
       }
    }

function iabLoadStop(event) {
    alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
}

function iabLoadError(event) {
    alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
}
```

Comment: This is not the thing I wanted. Only loading events won't work for me. I need to override the history buttons work. That means I should be able to control the next or back button click from inside the inAppBrowser view.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to hide `history buttons (BACK & FORWARD)` and `URL address` from `InAppBrowser's` nav-bar, then either comment on lines in `inAppBrowser.java`. Which is present at folder location

> platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\inAppBrowser.java

go to below lines or search for below lines and comment out those lines

```
actionButtonContainer.addView(back);
actionButtonContainer.addView(forward);
```

or you can comment out this line too.

```
toolbar.addView(actionButtonContainer);
```

And in order to hide the URL location you can comment out below line

```
toolbar.addView(edittext);
```

2. If you want to close the `InAppBrowser` using `Back` button then do perform step 1. After modify below lines which are written for `Close/Done` button.
   `closeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);`

`int closeResId = activityRes.getIdentifier("ic_action_previous_item", "drawable", cordova.getActivity().getPackageName());`

3. After that just build you project from CLI and Run it.

Happy Coding